# ASP.NET, MySQL and div elements - how to use for my online radio station site?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I'm converting my online radio station site from HTML to ASP.NET, and I've got a test copy running on my server.

However, in one of my ASPX files, the schedule page, I'm trying to extract content from the database to populate the DIV files, like this:

```
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
        <img src="headphones.gif" width=115 height=60>
        <div class="time">00:00</div>
        <div class="show"><h3><b>Non Stop Hits</b></h3>
            <p>Get more non-stop music through the night.</p></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
        <img src="empty.gif" width=115 height=60>
        <div class="time">08:00</div>
        <div class="show"><h3><a href="article.aspx?id=114934"><b>John Smith</a></b></h3>
            <p>John wakes you up on Sunday</p></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
        <img src="empty.gif" width=115 height=60>
        <div class="time">12:00</div>
        <div class="show"><h3><b>Non Stop Weekend</b></h3>
            <p>Your requests non-stop!</p></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
        <img src="headphones.jpg" width=115 height=60>
        <div class="time">16:00</div>
        <div class="show"><h3><a href="http://"><b>The 90s Weekend</a></b></h3>
            <p>Every song is a hit from the 90s!</p></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
        <img src="headphones.jpg" width=115 height=60>
        <div class="time">19:00</div>
        <div class="show"><h3><b>YourInternetstation.com</b></h3>
            <p>More non-stop music!</p></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

I'm used to SQL queries for this in PHP, but in ASP.NET how would you do it?
Also, although my files display as schedule.aspx, how would I rename them to schedule.customextension within IIS and (for each day) schedule.customextension?day=7

Is it possible to show a different page each day for the schedule within IIS?
I've had a go and they always show it in table format!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the first hurdle in mapping ASP.NET to your PHP experience.

For this you would likely use the [repeater control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You need to get your head around the fact that **HTML is not mixed in with the logic** as it is in PHP, they are seperated up into .aspx and .cs where controls map the two together.

In order to get the data into your app in the first place, take a look at the [data access tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials).